# For count data from a survey, do variance corrections for survey design imply that the Poisson distribution will not accurately model the counts?

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, poisson-distribution, count-data, stratification

I have categorical count data that comes from a complex survey. Each unit of analysis in the survey (`household`, `individual`, etc.) is put into one and only category per dimension, ranging from 2 to 20 categories per dimension. The number of dimensions exceeds 50. The survey reports a variance estimate corrected based on the clustering and stratification in the survey design for each count.

I have three closely related questions:

1. Does the fact that the variances for the cell counts depend on something other than and additional to the value of the count or the underlying cell probability imply that these cells are not distributed according to the Poisson distribution?
2. If not, why?
3. If so, can we say what distribution is probably the correct one, or what are good candidates? 
   I was thinking negative binomial, but that just gives you one more coefficient, while the survey results include a distinct variance correction for each cell.